# I'm trying to install homebrew in my 32 bit ubuntu machine. But it's not working and I got this error

Tags: ruby, linux, appium, homebrew, 32-bit

I used to site to install homebrew
https://confusedcoders.com/general-programming/mobile/how-to-install-appium-in-ubuntu

after I run this command I got below error on terminal
sh -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Linuxbrew/install/master/install.sh)"

Error in terminal:

Error: No Homebrew ruby 2.6.3_2 available for i686 processors!
Error: Failed to install Homebrew Portable Ruby and cannot find another Ruby 2.6!
If there's no Homebrew Portable Ruby available for your processor:

- install Ruby 2.6 with your system package manager (or rbenv/ruby-build)
- make it first in your PATH
- try again

Even I installed Ruby 2.6 in my machine, still I faced the same issue.
Can anyone help me to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

As documented in [here](https://docs.brew.sh/Installation), the official homebrew installation requirements are:

> - A 64-bit Intel CPU
> - macOS High Sierra (10.13) (or higher)
> - Command Line Tools (CLT) for Xcode: xcode-select --install, developer.apple.com/downloads or Xcode
> - A Bourne-compatible shell for installation (e.g. bash or zsh)

For 32 bit machines, there is something called [Tigerbrew](https://github.com/mistydemeo/tigerbrew) maintained by Homebrew core maintainer. Follow the separate [installation](https://github.com/mistydemeo/tigerbrew#installation) over there, you should be in the good state to install your first formula.

Comment: Tigerbrew is for macOS, not Linux, so that won't help the OP.